# Google analytics specific link to google play

Tags: google-analytics, google-play

I have an app in google play.
I'm planning to have an add to my app and I want to know the information for this specific link.
Is it possible? how should I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want Google analytics [Google Play campaign attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns)

Comment: Thanks! that's what i needed !

Comment: FYI: It is polite on StackOverflow to accept and vote up an answer that is useful.